# How do you change the spacing between sections?

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I'm losing a lot of space in the document because the space between the text and a figure or the text of a section and the subsequent section is too large and I want to reduce it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...